# How to delete a conversation participant user by its identity

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I add users to conversations through API REST. For example I do:

```
await client.conversations
    .services(TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations(conversationSid)
    .participants.create({ identity: myIdentity });
```

Consider that I need to delete users from conversation only through API REST. I found out [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource) how to remove them by its sid. Is there any way to remove them by its identity? I need to do so because I don't keep trace of participant's sid into my DB. If I have to then I will.

So how would you face this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the SID. Thankfully when you create a participant in the conversation, the API responds with the SID.

```js
const participant = await client.conversations
    .services(TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations(conversationSid)
    .participants.create({ identity: myIdentity });

console.log(participant.sid);
```

So, when you create the participant, store their SID. Then when you need to update or delete them, you can fetch their SID from your own database.